# Specify helper path to use when calling view helper

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have multiple view helper paths, some of which might contain view helpers with the same name as other registered paths.

For example `/view/helper/path1` might contain `myViewHelper`, while `/view/helper/path2` may also contain a *different* view helper, but with the same name `myViewHelper`.

Obviously I might run into some problems when calling `$this->myViewHelper`; I can't rely on getting the view helper I want, as this is dependent on which path is at the top of the stack.

Is there a way that I can specify which path I want to use at any given time? A fully qualified path, if you like.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces might be what you are looking for: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

However if you give a bit more context to your problem, there might be a better implementation, it's hard to tell from what you've said so far.

When would you use helper in path1 over helper in path2?

Comment: I considered using namespaces but I'm not sure (how) it would help with selecting a given path from the stack. In terms of context: what I have is a "page renderer" class which will take a list of view helpers from a config file and render them with options. This renderer should only use view helpers from a given helper path. It seems that I might be better off either clearing the view helper path stack and registering the single path I require or (potentially better option) using a separate view object for my renderer only.